# C++ manipulating mdb database

Tags: c++, database, ms-access, native

I want to create an app based on the content of a .mdb file, I searched for libraries to do that in native but they all needed requirements, I want a way to read these files using native code(C++) only, so I could use the library in multiple platforms.

Thx,
Regards

Comment: You could download the Jackcess source code from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jackcess/files/jackcess/) and then port the code from Java to C++. Good luck with that.

Comment: It's unlikely you will be able to use MS Access databases on different platforms than windows.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ - [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) does it with pure Java (any platform) so it's *possible*, just a huge amount of work.

Answer (score 1):

The `.mdb` file format is specific to the Microsoft Access ("Jet") database engine, which is proprietary and specific to Windows.  (Furthermore, it is an *evolving* file-format, although it does not seem to continue to be in active development now.)  There is one, and *only* one, "correct" way to use it, and that is: to use Microsoft's library and surrounding framework, on Microsoft's operating system.

If, indeed, you need to use a "file-based SQL engine," "on multiple platforms," then I would cordially suggest that you *instead* use a database file format that was specifically designed for such purposes:  **SQLite**.

Mind you, the two are not the same.  They're the product of two entirely different design teams who had different purposes in mind.  The SQLite team knowingly did not adhere strictly to the SQL standard.  But, what they *did* do was to create a public domain(!) database engine, which uses a single file, and which was specifically designed to be cross-platform.  Meanwhile, the Jet team designed their engine specifically, and solely, in support of the Access (and Excel) products of their company.

Comment: thx for ur detailed answer, but I am aware of this, I already have a .mdb database created by someone else, I do not want to create a new database, I want a way to read it in C++ or at least convert it to another format that has a cross-platform library.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  SQLite would be a good choice, IMHO, and one pragmatic way to do it would be to ... "do as the Romans do."  Do that step on Windows, using MS-Access.  There's an ODBC/DAO driver for SQLite, of course.  Then, take that now-transportable file and run with it.  So far as I am aware, you *can't* read or write an MDB file (successfully) without "using the Jet library, on Windows."  So... use that tool, in that environment, to one-time-transfer the file to a format that *is* transportable.  (I wouldn't waste any *coding* time on *that* step.)