# Why is the "add reference" list in my C++-Project in VS2017 empty?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

When trying to add a reference to my Visual C++ project in VS 2017 (I chose "empty project" when creating) the list of references to select from is empty, as shown in the following picture (it's in german but I hope it nevertheless gets the point across):

[image: image: "Add Reference"]

Although I haven't used VS or coded in Visual C++ in the past, I'm fairly certain that the reference list should not be empty and should instead show a list of possible references to choose from.

I have created the project from scratch, just added some existing .cpp, .hpp and .h files. Even when creating a new "windows desktop application" or a "windows console application" the reference list is empty.

I want to work with a MS Access Database (.mdb) via DAO and therefore need to add a reference to the *COM Microsoft DAO Object Library* as explained [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/808747/Csharp-VB-NET-Cplusplus-CLI-Read-and-write-MS-Acce) (correct me if I'm wrong).

My problem is nowhere to be found when doing a google search (the only solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42077417/empty-list-in-visual-studio-references) doesn't work for me), therefore I created this post and hope someone here can tell me how to fix this issue.

Comment: You can't add a reference to DAO anyways because you aren't using C++/CLI, which isn't supported anymore.

Comment: That is not how it is done.  Add Reference lets you pick another project that creates a library (DLL or static).  For a COM reference you must use the [#import directive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8etzzkb6.aspx) in source code.  Google "#import dao360.dll" to find sample code.  Using the [CDaoDatabase class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34fa51ss.aspx) is another way, probably more practical when you never used COM components before.

Comment: Thanks Hans Passant!!! I will try both solutions you provided and report back if those don't work.

Answer (score 1):

It's empty because you are in the wrong subdirectory. You are under "Solution", and in your solution, there is only one project, AM. If you add another project to the same solution, you'll see it appearing in the list.

You can try to go under the other subdirectory, but I doubt you'll find anything, because you have a non-CLI C++ application, and those applications don't support "references" (it's just not a thing).

Comment: Wow that was a fast answer, thank you very much. So how am I able to work with the .mdb databases via DAO if I can't add references to my project? Do i have to create a new "CLI C++" application and if so, how?

Comment: Don't know, you'd have to find some library for that. AFAIK you can't anymore, it isn't supported anymore.

Comment: And btw, you are right: I first switched to the other subdirectory (which was also empty), but when adding a new project to my solution it shows those newly created projects.

Comment: Why isn't it supported anymore, there has to be a way to work with .mdb?

Comment: Looks like it is not possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164707/c-manipulating-mdb-database

Comment: So just to be sure if I understand the content of the link you provided (Sorry I'm fairly new to Visual Studio and C++): Is there no way at all to work with .mdb in visual c++ or is that statement only true regarding the use of DAO to do so?

Comment: I will try Hans Passants solution provided as a comment to my original question and report back if that didn't work out.

Comment: in visual C++ yes, but it's not supported anymore.